# How to extend IDocumentListener in eclipse for creating plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to create a plugin which monitors the change in a document.

I am interested in adding a marker in the text editor when the document is changed.

I observed that for the class - **IDocumentListener** the method **documentChanged** is getting called whenever there is a change.

However, I am unable to implement this as plugin as this interface does not have an extension point.

Can you help me with extending **IDocumentListener** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's instructive to look at an existing open-source plugin to see how it does a similar task. Let's look at [Bracketeer](https://github.com/chookapp/Bracketeer) as an example.

The starting point is a class that implements `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin`. For plugins that have a UI, it's useful to implement `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin` which provides additional functionality. This class is commonly called the "activator", and indeed in Bracketeer it's called [`Activator`](https://github.com/chookapp/Bracketeer/blob/master/Bracketeer/src/com/chookapp/org/bracketeer/Activator.java). It's registered as the plugin's activator class in the [`MANIFEST.MF`](https://github.com/chookapp/Bracketeer/blob/master/Bracketeer/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) file using a line like:

```
Bundle-Activator: com.chookapp.org.bracketeer.Activator
```

The `Activator` class overrides `Plugin.start()`, which will be called by the runtime when the plugin is loaded. The overridden `start()` method sets up a **part listener**.

The part listener is a class that implements the `IPartListener2` interface. In Bracketeer, it's called [`PartListener`](https://github.com/chookapp/Bracketeer/blob/master/Bracketeer/src/com/chookapp/org/bracketeer/core/PartListener.java). On setup, it calls `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()` to get a hold of the `IWorkbench`, and `IWorkbench.getWorkbenchWindows()` to get a list of currently open windows (at the time the plugin starts). It then registers itself with each window via `IWorkbenchWindow.getPartService().addPartListener()`.

In addition, to handle new windows being opened after the plugin is loaded, `PartListener` also implements `IWindowListener`, and registers itself as a window listener via `IWorkbench.addWindowListener()`. This allows the `PartListener` to handle new windows opening by overriding `IWindowListener.windowOpened()`, and register itself as a part listener for the new windows.

As a part listener, `PartListener` overrides `IPartListener2.partActivated()` and `partOpened()` to handle workbench parts (which include **editors**) being opened or activated. In those methods, it checks whether the part is an `IEditorPart`; if so, it gets a hold of the editor part's **document** (see [`PartListener.getPartDocument()`](https://github.com/chookapp/Bracketeer/blob/master/Bracketeer/src/com/chookapp/org/bracketeer/core/PartListener.java#L360)), which is an `IDocument`.

Finally, having an `IDocument`, it can register any `IDocumentListener` it wants via `IDocument.addDocumentListener(IDocumentListener)`.

(There are some details I'm glossing over, such as manually calling `partActivated()` for every workbench part that's already open at the time the plugin is started. See the Bracketeer code for the full details.)

All of these are public APIs, and none of this requires any extension point to be implemented.